# hwo to introduce Mobile first concept in a website creation

Tags: web, mobile, responsive, device, dimension

Good morning,

I want to creat a websibe mobile first but i want to know this before.

Good morning,

To respect the mobile-first concept, do I have to give the dimensions of a mobile device to my container from the start?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css framework like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) of [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) to make your design responsive to various devices.